# C# - Sending an Email from BlueHost

Tags: c#, email, smtp, bluehost

I have BlueHost, and I cannot get this to work with C#. I have taken the details right off of the page where I login:

[image]

I then use this code to try and send an email:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress("toEmail@site.com", "toEmail@site.com")
};
message.IsBodyHtml = false;
message.To.Add("email@site.com");
message.Subject = "my subject";
message.Body = "body";
message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
{
    Port = 465,
    Host = "box263.bluehost.com",
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myEmail@site.com", "myPassword"),
    Timeout = 10000,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false
};
client.Send(message);
```

It throws an error saying that it times out, even though it has plenty of time(10 seconds). Even if I don't put a timeout time, then it just sit for a while. I have also tried it without SSL, disabling 'EnableSsl', changing the port to '26', and changing the host to 'mail.embirk.com', but that also doesn't work. Also, this does work with 3rd party software such as Microsoft Outlook and stuff. Any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I also contacted a level II support tech at Bluehost, and they said that they are stumped also. They said they tried it with Thunderbird, and it all worked. They said that it may be looking for a certificate?

EDIT 2:

Could this Outlook registry thing help. (this works with Outlook if ran).

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\OMI Account Manager\Accounts\steve@embirk.com]
"DCEmail"=dword:00000002
"IMAP Server"="box263.bluehost.com"
"IMAP Port"=dword:000003e1
"SMTP Server"="box263.bluehost.com"
"SMTP Port"=dword:000001d1
"Connection Type"=dword:00000003
"IMAP User Name"="steve@embirk.com"
"SMTP Display Name"="steve@embirk.com"
"SMTP Email Address"="steve@embirk.com"
"SMTP Reply To Email Address"="steve@embirk.com"
"SMTP Organization Name"=""
"Account Name"="steve@embirk.com"
"IMAP Timeout"=dword:0000003c
"SMTP Timeout"=dword:0000003c
"IMAP Secure Connection"=dword:00000001
"IMAP Skip Account"=dword:00000000
"IMAP Prompt for Password"=dword:00000001
"SMTP User Name"="steve@embirk.com"
"SMTP Use Sicily"=dword:00000002
"SMTP Secure Connection"=dword:00000001
"SMTP Split Messages"=dword:00000000
"SMTP Prompt for Password"=dword:00000000
"IMAP Root Folder"=""
"IMAP Polling"=dword:00000001
"IMAP Poll All Folders"=dword:00000001
"IMAP Dirty"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, but have you tried contacting the customer support at bluehost?

Comment: Yes, I contacted a level II support tech at Bluehost, and they said that they are stumped also. They said they tried it with Thunderbird, and it all worked. They said that it may be looking for a certificate?

Comment: Quote from BH: *Bluehost does provide a free Shared SSL certificate available to all accounts residing on a shared IP address. For more information about the Shared SSL Certificate* -> https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/473

Comment: I just wanted to clarify a point. When you say it works with other email clients, do you mean it works to hit `box263.bluehost.com` from your local machine, or with other email clients running on your server?

Comment: Are you using the NetMail or WebMail object?

Comment: Did you get this working?  I am having issues as well.

Comment: I had the same issue today, SMTP on port `465` works perfectly in Python but times out with C#. The fix for me was to use port `587` and use "boxXXX.bluehost.com" as the host instead of "mail.mydomain.com", as OP is doing in his question.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to declaring the credentials outside the client block and the assigning it to the client credentials.

Actually get rid of the block altogether.

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");


client.Credentials = myCred;
client.port = 465,
client.Host = "box263.bluehost.com",
client.EnableSsl = true,
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myEmail@site.com", "myPassword"),
client.Timeout = 10000,
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false
```

Comment: This makes little sense, as you set the Credentials first, and then later set them again...

Comment: So the NetworkCredential is part of system.net, while the client.Credentials is part of System.Net.Mail. Two separate objects.
You are instantiating the NetworkCredential and then assigning it to the message. This is not the same as setting the credentials twice.

Comment: the moment you set "UseDefaultCredentials" it wipes out any value in the "Credentials " property.  As such, you should set the credentials AFTER you have set this property